# How to format java LocalDate in angular's ui-grid

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using AngularJS for front end of an application and for showing db data I am using Angular's ui-grid. Back end of the project is written in Spring MVC and for date in Models I am using java LocalDate. Everything works fine except LocalDate object. Ui-grid is not formatting it properly. I have seen several examples for formatting Date object, but so far none of them working as i expected.

Here is my code in my controller:

```
var AtmGroupController = function ($scope, $http, $modal, $log) {

$scope.title_page = 'List of Atm Groups';


$scope.fetchProviderList = function () {
    $http.post('/atmGroup/atmGroups').success(function (atmGroups) {
        $scope.atmGroups = atmGroups;
    });
};

$scope.filterOptions = {filterText: ''};

$scope.columnDefs = [
    {field: 'id', displayName: 'Id'},
    {field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'},
    {field: 'deviceSchema.name', displayName: 'Device Schema'},
    {
        field: 'date',
        displayName: 'Date Registered',
        cellFilter: 'date'
    },
    {field: 'screenMenu.name', displayName: 'Menu Name'},
    {
        name: 'edit',
        displayName: 'Edit',
        cellTemplate: '<button id="editBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="edit(row.entity)" >Edit</button>'
    }
];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'atmGroups',
    columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs
};

$scope.fetchProviderList();

};
```

What I have tried:

```
cellFilter: 'date'
date:'yyyy-MM-dd'
cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS Z\''
cellFilter = 'date:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"';
```

but my LocalDate object is being displayed like:

```
{
   "year":2015,
   "month":"JULY",
   "dayOfMonth":7,
   "dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY",
   "era":"CE",
   "dayOfYear":188,
   "leapYear":false,
   "monthValue":7,
   "chronology":{
      "calendarType":"iso8601",
      "id":"ISO"
   }
}
```

I think there should be some easy way to format this type of json data in ui-grid, but how it is done?

Comment: Pls add a fiddle for this problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ui-grid, but if your problem is only to parse and a particular format of a date. Then you can try creating a filter like this.

```
appWebApp.filter('appdate', function($filter, client) {
return function(input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return "";
    }
    var serrdate = client.getDateTime(input);
    var _date = $filter('date')(serrdate, 'MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss');
    return _date.toUpperCase();
};});
```

and use it like this `<td ng-bind="instance.createdTs | appdate"></td>`

Comment: I do not think that it is possible with ui-grid, but anyway, thanks.